# How do I modifiy this array input code?

Tags: java, arrays

What would you do to the following code to, specically check that the array tokens have two elements, if there is a problem with the format of the data inform the user but carry on accepting input. How would you do this? Also how would you accept an input of "quit", put name and get name? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInput {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b; 
        String student[] = new String [50];
        String mark [ ]= new String [50];
        int i = 0;
        while ((b = s.nextLine()) != null){
            if (b.equals("quit")){
                break;
            }
            String Tokens[] = b.split(' ');
            // System.out.println(Tokens[0] + ' ' + Tokens[1]);
            student[i] = Tokens[0];
            mark[i] = Tokens[1];
            i++;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println(student[j] + ' ' + mark[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using parallel arrays is an anti-pattern. Use a `Map` or even a `List<Student>`.

Comment: This is a textbook case of object denial. You should have an object to store `student` and `mark` together. Suppose you wanted to sort by `mark`, that would be very hard to do correctly with two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
while ((b=s.nextLine()) != null)
{
    if (b.equals("quit")) break ;
    String Tokens[] = b.split(' ');
    if (Tokens.length == 2) {
        student[i]=Tokens[0];
        mark[i]=Tokens[1];
        i++;         
    } else {
       //inform user that its format is incorrect..
    }
    // System.out.println(Tokens[0] + ' ' + Tokens[1]);
}
```